# 3 column layout with middle column fluid and appear first in HTML code, others fixed width

Tags: html, css

I want to make a classic 3-column layout like this:

```
|  |      |  |
|L |  M   |R |
|  |      |  |
```

and I was asked to use following html structure:
as you can see, the `Main` div is the first node of #container

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="M">Main</div>
    <div id="L">Left</div>
    <div id="R">Right</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How to do that with and without css3 new features?

UPDATE:
`#L` and `#R` has a fixed width, say, 200px. `#container` has the same width of window(ignore body margin)  `#M`'s left border touchs right border of `#L` and `#M`'s right border touchs left border of `#R`.

Comment: -1 could you please provide any attempts you may have done? I'll be happy to remove my down vote if you have tried to achieve this effect yourself.

Comment: @JoshPowell I tried to give `display:table` to container and `display:table-cell` to `M,L,R` but the `M` remain first. and I was stuck. I also tried `float` approach, but this approach require `L,R` appear before `M`.

Comment: Look at my answer for help with having that html structure. Also edit your answer and I'll remove the down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do to achieve this layout.

```
#M {
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: brown;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

#L {
  width: 20%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #c1c1c1;
}

#R {
  width: 20%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #c1c1c1;
}
```

This way is 100% responsive but if you wanted a fixed width for the outer divs you could do that as well.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T3Q97/1/)

Comment: Glad I could have helped and best of luck in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually something like [this](http://jsbin.com/OjUPEP/1/edit) one?

```
#M {
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  width:33%;
}


#L {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  background:lime;
  width:33%;
}


#R {
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  background:yellow;
  width:33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is actually possible with flexboxes. I really wouldn't want to sacrifice the browser support for the order of the markup, though.

This solution doesn't work with the `#M` element at the top.. and except for some trickery using positioning I don't think this is possible.

If you move the `#M` element to the bottom, this would work:

```
#M {
    background-color: #eeffff;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 200px;
}
#L {
    background-color: #ffeeff;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 180px;
}
#R {
    background-color: #ffffee;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

In that case, unless the parent container is fixed width, the middle would be flexible width while left and right are static. But you could also set margin and width of the `#L` and `#R` elements as percentage, for example.

Comment: Thanks @MildlyInteresting, `#M` at bottom is relatively easy. But `#M` must at top.